# Sending an email to a subscriber using a triggered send with the exact target soap api

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am trying to send an email to a subscriber using a triggered send,i'm using the soap api and can't seem to trigger the send.

Below is the soap body of the soap call, any idea why this isn't working?

Note: The triggered send definition is running.

```
  <CreateRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <Objects xsi:type="TriggeredSend">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <TriggeredSendDefinition>
           <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
           <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
           <CustomerKey>Test TS</CustomerKey>
        </TriggeredSendDefinition>
        <Subscribers>
           <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
           <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
           <EmailAddress>test@test.co.uk</EmailAddress>
            <SubscriberKey>test@test.co.uk</SubscriberKey>
        </Subscribers>
       </Objects>
</CreateRequestMsg>
```

Comment: What are you using for authentication?  I was expecting to see an oauth token or something in this packet.

Comment: @Timothy i have omitted the security header and only posted the soap body. As far as i am aware an oauth token is not needed for authentication, i have been using my exact target user login and password in the soap header and everything has been working fine.

Comment: Have you ever been able to make any type of API call with that Username?  Do you have any other "Required" attributes that also need to be passed?  Another thing to check is that the Triggered Send Definition is running and your email is passing validation.

Comment: @Jeremy I have been able to make retrieve calls using the the username,but can't seem to to get create to work. As far as i am aware i have provided all the required elements.The triggered send definition is running and the email is valid.

Comment: Thanks @JCS - Does your Triggered Send Definition add subscribers to a List and/or Data Extensions?  If there are fields that are not nullable (or Required Attributes for lists) on your DE, they will need to be passed on your call as well.  Are you getting a response back from your call with any error codes/messages?  If needed, can you reach out to Help@exacttarget with this info?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work, needed to change the name of root element of the soap body to CreateRequest, and add a client element with the  id sub element, the id element is the MID of your exact target account.

Below is the working soap body that can trigger a send.

```
<CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Objects xsi:type="TriggeredSend">
       <Client>
          <ID>123456</ID>
     </Client>
  <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
           <TriggeredSendDefinition>
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
               <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
              <CustomerKey>Key</CustomerKey>
         </TriggeredSendDefinition>
         <Subscribers>
             <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
             <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
             <EmailAddress>email@example.com</EmailAddress>
           <SubscriberKey>email@example.com</SubscriberKey>    
        </Subscribers>
    </Objects>
</CreateRequest>
```

Found examples of calling the exact target api using soap envelopes below.

http://help.exacttarget.com/Global/Documentation/APIStarterKits/SOAPv3.zip

Comment: What does the value of id "ID" under "Client" tag imply here? What is expected in this value?